# BLOB image file cannot be updated - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, image, blob

I am new to Laravel. While adding the update option dynamically into my site, the BLOB image is not being updated. Here is my function :

```
public function update_giftcard($id , Request $data){
    $gift['name'] = $data->name;
    $gift['description'] = $data->description;

    $gift['category'] = $data->category;


    /*IMG STORAGE*/
    if($data->hasFile('img')) {
        $image = $data->file('img')->getClientOriginalName();
        $data->file('img')->move("uploads", $image);
        $gift['image'] = $image;
    }

    Giftcards::where('id' , $id)->first()->update($gift);
}
```

Here when I do `echo $gift['image']`, the filename is printed successfully and the image is being uploaded successfully too but it is not being updated in the mysql database.

Hope I get an answer, thanks.

Comment: I do not see where you save the image file into a blob. I can see you saving the name of the image only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating the data using the mass assignment. Did you add 'image' in $fillable?

Go to your model Giftcards and add

```
protected $fillable = [
    'image'
];
```

Comment: I did do the mass assignment but upon rechecking there was a typo in the $fillable causing the error.